# Change grid lines or border for a single cell in a wxGrid

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I trying to set up the cells in a `wxGrid` so that some of them have a thicker or thinner border. I figured out how to do it for entire rows or columns (i.e. overriding `wxGrid::GetColGridLinePen()` and `wxGrid::GetRowGridLinePen()`), but I cannot figure out how to change the border of just a single cell.

I think it should involve a `wxGridCellRenderer` but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to use it.

I have looked at the `grid` sample but that did not help me with my problem.

Could anyone nudge me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do indeed need to use a custom renderer to customize the appearance of individual cells and the grid sample is the right place to look. There are, of course, a lot of things going on there, but search for `MyGridCellRenderer` for an example of using a custom renderer -- it's really not difficult, you just derive from some existing renderer (e.g. `wxGridCellStringRenderer` for the cells showing text), override its `Draw()` method, call the base class method to draw the text and then draw your own border.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! That sounds simple enough. When I looked through the sample, o got stuck on the star cell renderer and somehow that confused me enough so that I didn't look any further. I'll try it out soon and will mark the answer when I figured it out!

Comment: Thank you again, it works!

However, it seems that the grid lines are drawn somewhere downstream from where the grid cell renderer draws. So when I want to have no border for some cells by means of a custom grid cell renderer but grid lines generally on, they end up being drawn anyway.

It seems that in that case you have to pass a custom grid renderer to all cells so that some of them draw the grid lines and some of them don't.

Comment: Yes, grid lines are drawn by the grid itself and not by each cell. If you need to suppress borders for at least some cells, I'm afraid your only solution is to suppress the grid lines globally with `EnableGridLines(false)` and then draw all of them from your renderer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating the following custom grid cell renderer to have full control of how the borders are drawn:

```cpp
class CellBorderRenderer : public wxGridCellNumberRenderer
{
   public:
    CellBorderRenderer(const wxPen& top=*wxBLACK_PEN, const wxPen& right=*wxBLACK_PEN,
                       const wxPen& bottom=*wxBLACK_PEN, const wxPen& left=*wxBLACK_PEN,
                       bool hideSelection=false)
    : pen_({top, right, bottom, left}), hideSelection_(hideSelection)
    {

    }
    void Draw(wxGrid &grid, wxGridCellAttr &attr, wxDC &dc, const wxRect &rect, 
              int row, int col, bool isSelected) override
    {
      attr.SetAlignment(wxALIGN_CENTER, wxALIGN_CENTER);
      wxGridCellNumberRenderer::Draw(grid, attr, dc, rect, row, col, hideSelection_ ? false : isSelected);

      std::array<wxPoint, 5> points{rect.GetTopLeft(), rect.GetTopRight(),
                                    rect.GetBottomRight(), rect.GetBottomLeft(),
                                    rect.GetTopLeft()};

      for (unsigned i = 0; i < pen_.size(); ++i)
      {
        dc.SetPen(pen_[i]);
        dc.DrawLine(points[i], points[i+1]);
      }
    }
   private:
    std::array<wxPen, 4> pen_{*wxBLACK_PEN, *wxBLACK_PEN, *wxBLACK_PEN, *wxBLACK_PEN};
    bool hideSelection_{false};
};
```

I then disabled the grid lines and passed an instance of this class to every single cell like so:

```cpp
const auto thickBlackPen = wxPen(*wxBLACK, this->FromDIP(2));
for (int r = 0; r < mygrid->GetNumberRows(); ++r)
{
  for (int c = 0; c < mygrid->GetNumberCols(); ++c)
  {
    wxPen topPen{*wxLIGHT_GREY_PEN}, rightPen{*wxLIGHT_GREY_PEN}, bottomPen{*wxLIGHT_GREY_PEN}, leftPen{*wxLIGHT_GREY_PEN};
    bool hideSelection = false;
    if (c % 3 == 0)  // 3x3 subgrid boxes have thick border
    {
      rightPen = thickBlackPen;
    }
    if (r % 3 == 0)  // 3x3 subgrid boxes have thick border
    {
      bottomPen = thickBlackPen;
    }

    mygrid->SetCellRenderer(r, c, new CellBorderRenderer(topPen, rightPen, bottomPen, leftPen, hideSelection));

  }
}
```

In this (reduced) example there would be a thicker black line every three columns and rows. This could of course be adapted to any other kind of border pattern.